# Referencing specific button from one clicklistener

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, android-button, android-tablelayout

I'm having a problem figuring out how to work with 1 unique button out of the list of buttons that I've added to a TableLayout, from an array.

Below is the code I'm using to get this done, and the behavior I am seeing now is (naturally) that the buttons all respond to the listener. I want the Button that was clicked (and that button alone) to behave in some way.

I've tried combinations of setTag(i) on the declaration of the buttons from the array, and then inside the listener I getTag() and use that value as the index for the array, but to no avail.

I have also tested with specifying the listener explicitly for the button at index 0 from the array, what that does is truly add a listener only to that specified button, but when that button is clicked, the rest respond as well.

Ideally, the code below is what I would like to achieve, having the button's width increase to about 300px whenever it is clicked. I am stomped by this while I've done it more than I can remember in other projects...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
private void initializeTableRows(TableLayout stringsTable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] strings = { "d", "g", "d", "g", "b", "d" };
    addRowsToTable(strings, stringsTable);
}

private void addRowsToTable(String[] strings, TableLayout stringsTable) {
    TableRow tableRows[] = new TableRow[strings.length];
    Button[] stringNames = new Button[strings.length];
    final Button[] tuneButtons = new Button[strings.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        stringNames[i] = new Button(this);
        stringNames[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_frame);
        stringNames[i].setText(strings[i].toUpperCase());
        stringNames[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        tuneButtons[i] = new Button(this);
        tuneButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_frame);
        tuneButtons[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tuneButtons[i].setText("Tune");

        tuneButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
                clickedButton.setWidth(300);
            }
        });

            tableRows[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tableRows[i].addView(stringNames[i]);
        tableRows[i].addView(tuneButtons[i]);


        tableRows[i].setPadding(0, 0, 0, 40);

        stringsTable.addView(tableRows[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use setId, getId to determine which button was clicked

Comment: I did use setId() upon creation at each tuneButtons[i], and inside onClick I used v.getId() and got the ID back. After that, I tried "tuneButtons[id].setWidth(400)" and I still saw all of the buttons in the list get affected. This is why I am so stupefied, I've tried all of what I'm probably going to see in the comments! Thanks for answering though

Comment: If you look at the code, the behavior is perfectly expected. One listener is being added to an array of buttons, through the use of a loop. All the buttons are getting the same listener stating the same behavior...

So even if I say setId() like `tuneButtons[i].setId(i);` and then inside onClick() I say `int buttonId = v.getId(); tuneButtons[buttonId].setWidth(400)`.. That reasoning is going to apply for all of the buttons inside the array, there is no differentiator that I can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been working all along, I was just erroneously using setWidth() on the button. I say erroneously because right now I just tested with setText() and the text changed only for the button in question, not for anything else.

What I did realize when the text changed though, was, that all the other buttons in the tableLayout also expanded with the expansion of the button in question (to accommodate for the size of the new text being set). This was the fault of TableLayout behaving in this unwanted manner.